# Power BI - How do I use calculated values from various tables and store them in a separate table

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns, timeserieschart

I'm trying to figure out a solution to my problem. Basically we get a monthly report with about 3000 records and there's a bunch of reporting that is done on that, and there are calculations based on various columns. e.g.

| Date | Total usage | Recommended reduction | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 | 1000 | 500 | A |
| 01.01.2022 | 1300 | 70 | B |
| 01.01.2022 | 2000 | 900 | C |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

At the end of it Power BI kindly sums up the columns which is great, but now what I am trying to do is take the sum of these columns and store them in a summary table so that it would be something like this so that I could use it for a time series visual

| Month | Sum Total Usage | Sum Recommended Reduction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | 59720 | 12040 |
| February | 81020 | 20580 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I have no idea how to go about doing this. Is this the right way to go ? Or is there a way to create a visual without having to create a summary table ? I'm at a bit of a loss, so any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any DAX calculations for that. Simply pull your data onto the fields of a line chart visual like shown below. Note that you have to drill-down from Year to Month to actually see the lines.

[image]